# How to find duplicate integer value from a file while in append mode in C?

Tags: c

I am making a simple database to book restaurant seats using basic file handling. I want to check if the user has entered an already booked seat number. As I am inputting the seat number while in append mode, how do I check if the seat number inputted by the user is already stored in the file or not. Here is a piece of my code -:

```
struct restaurant
{
   int seats, seatNo, seatAmount, pizzaQt, burgerQt, drinkQt, pizzaPrice, burgerPrice, drinkPrice;
   char name[20], restaurantName[20];
   int foodTotal, total;
   int counter;
};

int book() 
{
    FILE *fp;

    struct restaurant r;

    char choice, choice1;

    r.counter=0;

    fp=fopen("Restaurant.txt", "a");

    if(fp==NULL)
    
    {
       printf("\nFailed to open the file.");
       exit(1);  
    }
    else
    {
     do
     {
       printf("Proceed to booking...");
       
       getch();

       printf("\n\t\t\t\t---BOOK SEAT---");
       
       printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your name : ");
       scanf("%s", r.name);
       printf("\n\t\t\tEnter the restaurant name (ABC, XYZ, PQR, EFG) : ");
       scanf("%s", r.restaurantName);
       printf("\n\t\t\tEnter the number of seats : ");
       scanf("%d", &r.seats);
       **printf("\n\t\t\tEnter the seat number(s) : ");
       scanf("%d", &r.seatNo);**
```

Comment: Rethink your architecture: Why don't you hold all data in memory?

Comment: @thebusybee Can you please explain in detail what you mean?

Comment: One way or another you will need to read in the existing data. You can't magically compare against data you don't have. Either read in all the data at the start or read it in as you need. Having one append file stream does not prevent you from doing that. Just open the file as a seperate stream.

Comment: You know what memory is, in contrast to your disk, don't you? A computer can only work with data in memory, so you have to read all data from disk to memory anyway, as kaylum says. If you need to compare data more than once, it is more efficient to hold all data in memory. Hint: variables live in memory. Now you need to do your homework and read your beginner's C book.